# Dependent unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have a program that gives an output based on parameters object as input and information stored in a database.

I am trying to test this program with 2 test cases, the first of which gives no parameters. My program would then create a default parameters object and return it as part of the output, and then the second test would make a specific change to the parameters object and give it back to the program as input.

Currently I am doing this by combining the two test cases into one, to be able to save the parameters object in a local variable and change it and use it for the second one:

```
def test_function:
    testData = {'name':"Test"}        
    response = self.app.post('/test', data=testData)
    # make assert statements for first response
    parameters = json.loads(response.data)['parameters']
    parameters['foo'] = "bar"
    testData['parameters'] = parameters
    response = self.app.post('/test', data=testData)
    # make assert statements for second response
```

Is there any way I could do this in two separate test cases? Or more importantly, SHOULD I do this in two separate test cases since the second one wouldn't be able to run if the first one doesn't work?

I cannot hard code the parameters object for the second test case because it is dependent on the data in the database, and part of the reason for testing is to see if the program works for different/no data.

Comment: Are you wanting to get the original values of the DB and then make changes and finally ensure those changes were made?

Comment: Not quite, but somewhere along those lines:

My function gets the original values of the DB and creates a parameters object with it if none exists and does some calculations. Then in the actual program the user would be able to alter the parameters via GUI, and then rerun the function with the new parameters. That is what I'm trying to emulate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting to develop multiple tests using a known beginning state look into using the [`setUp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#setupclass-and-teardownclass) function.

Here's a simple example from the python website:

```
import random
import unittest

class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.seq = range(10)

    def test_shuffle(self):
        # make sure the shuffled sequence does not lose any elements
        random.shuffle(self.seq)
        self.seq.sort()
        self.assertEqual(self.seq, range(10))

        # should raise an exception for an immutable sequence
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, random.shuffle, (1,2,3))

    def test_choice(self):
        element = random.choice(self.seq)
        self.assertTrue(element in self.seq)

    def test_sample(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            random.sample(self.seq, 20)
        for element in random.sample(self.seq, 5):
            self.assertTrue(element in self.seq)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: The beginning state isn't necessarily known as part of the reason I'm doing the testing is making sure the program runs with different/no data in the database.

Updated original post to convey that.

Comment: Would it be okay practice to run the self.app.post() once in the setUp just to get the parameters object and then use it again with a modified parameters object for the test cases?

Comment: @SepehrNazari The purpose of using `setUp` is to make sure your testing environment is in a known state (good or bad).  If that requires writing (post) to the DB then by all means this is good practice.  If the write to the DB is to start testing actual functionality of the DB then no.